# When migrating Django to deployment i get this error why?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

On my local machine there is no issue. Everything runs perfectly. Even python manage.py check --deploy brings up no issues on my local.
The error i get stops me from doing anything with the project seemingly no matter the manage command.
But when I run makemigrations on my external server for deployment it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "/opt/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "Report_report" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "Report_report"."id" FROM "Report_report" ORDER BY "R..
```

https://pastebin.com/L0waK5Nq

Comment: did you `migrate` all your changes to db on external server?

Comment: it wont allow me to try. i've literally just put the files on the server. its initial setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running a migration for a single app.
python manage.py migrate app

Try running it for the app that will generate the report table and then run the other migratons.

Comment: I still get the same issue. no matter which app i try to migrate/ make migrations.

Comment: Can you commentout the troublesome code (the model) make a migration and run a fake migration: python manage.py migrate --fake. Then uncomment the code run makemigrations and run an actually migration (without -- fake)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. Because the value of it was called used in other places by giving it a temp value it allowed me to complete the migration and then use the previous code once the table had been created.

Answer (score 0):

## **Understanding the problem**

Did you say you makemigrations, can makemigrations command border about the database content? I think what can give such error will be migrate command because that is what pushes all the made migrations to the database. As such, if a table wasn't created and the program tries to access it, such error will occur.

## **to fix the problem**

Try to remove all the codes accessing the table (read the traceback for the origin of the problem) and make sure nothing in your code is trying to access the table. At such, makemigrations will be able to create the files neccessary to create this table and when you. If you are using GIT to deploy, you do not need to run makemigrations as the (GIT add and commit commands will push all files in the migrations folder to the server) and only migrate command is needed to create all the necessary structures into the database including creation of your table. Looking at your traceback errors is very important in getting this problem solved.